# What to happend when I registerLocalNotification to a past time?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

If I register a NSLocalNotification to a past time,wheather it will destory automaticly,or it take one schedule count in the system and never destory.

As though,we know the loacalNotification is limit to the 64 counts,when the notification register to the past time got to the 64 counts.The other lotification Whether happend or not

Comment: i have tried this it caused my device to restart.

Comment: I run it in the simulator,and nothing happend.

Comment: strange i tried to set date of past and my simulator quit and my device restarted.

Comment: somebody tell me,this   notification will fires immediately.but it change nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a notification in the past time .. it will play right then.. and your app delegate's `didRecieveNotification` method is called.

Comment: I means "today" I register a new NSLocalNotification to "yesterday"

Comment: well i have read it somewhere...dont remember ... but if you create a notification for any time in the past .. like 10 min before..1hr before..etc.. the system will play it as soon as it is registered in code..that is now

Comment: OK.may in simulator have some thing different.I will run it in my iPad later